# Child table delete after Parent table update

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I use JPA Repository for update data From table User and then after success to update Child parent User_Role will Delete.

**Log & Database**

[image]
[image]

**Mapping Entity**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY , cascade= {CascadeType.ALL} )
@JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name =    "user_id"),inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roleList = new HashSet<>();
```

Create User and Delete User work fine.What i should check for fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

From Service Layer you need to **delete** all mapping by **userId** from table **User_Role** . Then again insert new mapping to this table. But both delete and insert are in **same transaction**.